# Fragment overlapping tab layout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fragment, android-tablayout

When I start my app everything is fine except fragment overlapping my tab layout. Switching tab is fine, but it seems that fragment layout cover whole screen instead being under layout. Does anyone know solution ?
Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWhmp.jpg
Hope I didn't forgot to add something, if so, ask me. 
Thanks.

ActivityMain

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabBar);
        TabItem tabItem1 = findViewById(R.id.tab1);
        TabItem tabItem2 = findViewById(R.id.tab2);
        TabItem tabItem3 = findViewById(R.id.tab3);
        final ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout
                .TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    }
}
```

PagerAdapter class

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private int numOfTabs;
    public PagerAdapter (FragmentManager fm, int numOfTabs) {
        super (fm);
        this.numOfTabs = numOfTabs;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new FragmentTab1();
            case 1:
                return new FragmentTab2();
            case 2:
                return new FragmentTab3();
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numOfTabs;
    }
}
```

Activity_Main xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabBar"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tab1"
            android:text="Tab 1" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tab2"
            android:text="Tab 2" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tab3"
            android:text="Tab 3" />
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tabBar" />
  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tabBar"
```

Instead of

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tabBar"
```

The first align the top of the fragment to that of the tablayout and they will overlap. The top of the fragment should instead be constrained to the bottom of the tabbar.